# Is this the correct usage of Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, cookies, moq

I have the following interface that provides me a way to work with cookies:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides an interface that makes it easy to work with cookies.
/// </summary>
public interface ICookies
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value of the <see cref="ICookies"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the cookie.</param>
    /// <returns>A string that represents the value in this cookie.</returns>
    string this[string name] { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes a new cookie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the cookie.</param>
    /// <param name="expiration">The <see cref="DateTime"/> when this cookie expires.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value that the cookie should have.</param>
    void Create(string name, string value, DateTime expiration);

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks wether a cookie with a specific name does exist.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the cookie.</param>
    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if the cookie does exists, otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.</returns>
    bool DoesExist(string name);

    #endregion
}
```

And I have the following manager that takes the ICookie interface from above to create cookies. And that class looks like the following:

```
/// <summary>
///     Provides an easy way to work with cookies on the server.
/// </summary>
public static class CookieManager
{
    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Writes a new cookie on the.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cookies">The <see cref="ICookies" /> that is responsible for working with cookies.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the cookie.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the cookie.</param>
    public static void Write(ICookies cookies, string name, string value)
    {
        if (!Exists(cookies, name))
        {
            cookies.Create(name, value, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
        }

        cookies[name] = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Reads a cookie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cookies">The <see cref="ICookies" /> that is responsible for working with cookies.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the cookie to read.</param>
    /// <returns>The value of the cookie.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="KeyNotFoundException">The cookie is not existing.</exception>
    public static string Read(ICookies cookies, string name)
    {
        return cookies[name];
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Check if a cookie does exists.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cookies">The <see cref="ICookies" /> that is responsible for working with cookies.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the cookie.</param>
    /// <returns><see langword="true" /> when the cookie does exists, otherwise <see langword="false" />.</returns>
    public static bool Exists(ICookies cookies, string name)
    {
        return cookies.DoesExist(name);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, I would like to write a Unit test that mocks the cookie interface to make sure it passes.

I would like to check the following:

- When I call CookieManager.Write a cookie should be written and I should be able to read it using the CookieManager.Read function. What's the correct approach for that because I've already tried everything (working with the Verifyable, Setup, SetupGet, SetupSet).

Quite important to say is that I'm working with Moq.

Here's what I have for the moment:

I have a constant first:

```
protected const string CookieReturnValue = "ReturnValue";
```

Then I have my mock of ICookie:

```
protected override void Arrange()
   {
       cookies = new Mock<ICookies>();

       cookies.Setup(c => c.Create(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()));
       cookies.SetupGet(c => c[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns(CookieReturnValue).Verifiable();
   }
```

Then the test is executed:

```
protected override void Act()
{
    CookieManager.Write(cookies.Object, "MyCookie", "MyValue");
    CookieManager.Read(cookies.Object, "MyCookie");
}
```

And at the very end, the test is verified:

```
cookies.Verify();
```

Now, this test is passing, but I'm not too sure if this is the correct way of testing since in my mock, I'm returning the constant 'CookieReturnValue'. I should be able to set it to the value entered as the second parameter in the 'cookies.Setup()' method, where the 2nd parameter holds the value of the cookie.

The main problem here is that the test is also passing if I'm not writing a cookie. I need to make sure that the test is only passing when I'm writing a cookie and then reading the same cookie again.

Can someone if this is the correct way of testing or where that I should adapt it in order to make sure it's working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have actually three tests.

The first one tests if the `CookieManager` checks if a cookie exists, and when not, call `Create`, then set the cookie:

```
var cookies = new Mock<ICookies>();

// there's no cookie
cookies.Setup(c => c.DoesExist(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);

CookieManager.Write(cookies.Object, "MyCookie", "MyValue");

// check if create was called with the right parameters
cookies.Verify(c => c.Create("MyCookie", "MyValue", It.IsAny<DateTime>()));
// check if the cookie was set
cookies.VerifySet(mock => mock["MyCookie"] = "MyValue");
```

---

The second one tests if the `CookieManager` checks if a cookie exists, and when it does, don't call `Create`, then set the cookie:

```
// there's a cookie
cookies.Setup(c => c.DoesExist(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

CookieManager.Write(cookies.Object, "MyCookie", "MyValue");

// check if create was NOT called
cookies.Verify(c => c.Create(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()), Times.Never);
// check if the cookie was set
cookies.VerifySet(mock => mock["MyCookie"] = "MyValue");
```

---

The third one tests if the CookieManager attempts to read the cookie:

```
var cookies = new Mock<ICookies>();

CookieManager.Read(cookies.Object, "MyCookie");

// check if the indexer was used with the right key
cookies.Verify(c => c["MyCookie"]);
```

---

Note: simply calling `cookies.Verify()` does nothing on its own. You either have to provide a delegate to `Verify`, like I did in my examples, or call `VerifyAll` to verify all `SetUps`.

Also, you could make these tests more strict by e.g. using `Times.Once` or `MockBehavior.Strict`.

For example, the first test could also be written as:

```
var cookies = new Mock<ICookies>(MockBehavior.Strict);

// there's no cookie
cookies.Setup(c => c.DoesExist("MyCookie")).Returns(false);
// so one has to be created with the right parameters
cookies.Setup(c => c.Create("MyCookie", "MyValue", It.IsAny<DateTime>()));
cookies.SetupSet(mock => mock["MyCookie"] = "MyValue");

CookieManager.Write(cookies.Object, "MyCookie", "MyValue");

cookies.VerifyAll();
```

Also, I don't know why the `CookieManager` sets the cookie value *again* after it just created it with `cookies.Create(...)`.

---

Furthermore, there's no need to setup the mock to return the constant `CookieReturnValue`  and then check if that constant is actually returnd my that mock. This would not test the `CookieManager`, but rather the mock object itself, which is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and working out a solution for my problem. I highly appreciate it.